# OpenShot: move multiple items on timeline or insert time span

Tags: gnome, video-editing

So I created a small trailer in OpenShot (1.4.3, Debian). Now I want to prepend some titles, so I need a way to move all items on the timeline forward by a certain amount of seconds, or alternatively a function to insert a time span at the cursor.

How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it on a track-by-track basis. For each track

- select the *first* clip
- right-click and from the context menu choose 'Shift Clips' and enter the amount of seconds

So with five tracks, you have to repeat this five times.

Comment: What context menu?

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert your new clip at the beginning of an unused track (or a track where there is room for it).
2. Drag a box on all the clips you want to shift.
3. Click and drag your selection to the right.  If snapping is enabled, it will be easy to place at the right spot.